# SchematicsNestApplication schema warning on running `nest new my-project` with @nestjs/cli v8.0.2

Tags: javascript, console-application, nestjs

Upgraded to @nestjs/cli v8.0.2 and when running `nest new my-project` I get the following warning:

`"SchematicsNestApplication" schema is using the keyword "id" which its support is deprecated. Use "$id" for schema ID.`

Tested on fresh Windows and Ubuntu virtual machines with the same result.

Is this an actual problem or a warning we can ignore? I did not experience this issue with @nestjs/cli version 7.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

This is a change between `@angular-devkit/` between v11 and v12. It's more for the Nest schematics to be updated than a problem with your code or anything like that. Feel free to ignore it